# passing intent from widget config activity to AppWidgetProviderClass

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-widget

I created App Widget and configuration activity to configure app widget .In my configure activity has number of image views,where have to choose only one image view for my 1*1 widget .I implementing it in configuration activity of the widget .

below is the image of configuration activity 
[image: configuration activity]

code for setting the image in widget

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget,R.drawable.feed_detail_share);
            Intent defineIntent = new Intent(ConfigurationActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
            defineIntent.putExtra("from_widget",true);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(ConfigurationActivity.this,0 /* no requestCode */, defineIntent, 0 /* no flags */);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_widget, pendingIntent1);
```

after OK button is clicked
[image: widget]

below is the image when the device is switched on (when the device switched on the widget is empty)
  [image: empty widget]

```
public class WidgetProviderSmall extends AppWidgetProvider {
Context context;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    if (appWidgetIds != null) {
        int N = appWidgetIds.length;        
        for (int mAppWidgetId : appWidgetIds) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateSmallWidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            intent.setAction("FROM WIDGET PROVIDER");
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }
}

public static class UpdateSmallWidgetService extends IntentService {
    public UpdateSmallWidgetService() {         
        super("UpdateWidgetService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(UpdateSmallWidgetService.this);

        int incomingAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        if (incomingAppWidgetId != INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            try {
                updateNewsAppWidget(appWidgetManager, incomingAppWidgetId,
                        intent);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }

        }

    }

    public void updateNewsAppWidget(AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("String package name", this.getPackageName());
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.layout_appwidget_small);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
}
```

I didnt update the AppWidget in AppWidgetProvider class .I want to do that by passing an intent from widget config activity to AppWidgetProviderClass and I have no idea on it

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Post the code of your AppWidgetProvider please.

Comment: do you have permission in manifest?

Comment: i didnt add any permission

Comment: you have to add permission then..check out this.https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html